# i can not use variable as javascript argument

Tags: javascript

i am using Javascript on my page.
there is a problem when i use variable to send parameter to function,
when i write complete parameters directly as argument it works good like here

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
        var X = new MediaController({ContainerDiv:"player",MediaUrl:"test.flv"}');
</script>
```

but as i use a temp to put this argument in it, and then use temp as argument function it does not work!

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var temp;
       temp = '{ContainerDiv:"player",MediaUrl:"test.flv"}';
        var X = new MediaController(temp);
</script>
```

is there a point i missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning a String to the `temp` variable, which isn't the same as assigning the corresponding object. Instead of this

```
temp = '{ContainerDiv:"player",MediaUrl:"test.flv"}';
```

just do this:

```
temp = {ContainerDiv:"player",MediaUrl:"test.flv"};
```

and it should work the same.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in a string, not an object.

```js
var temp = {ContainerDiv: "player", MediaUrl: "test.flv"};
var X = new MediaController(temp);
```